# How can I change UIView size on scroll w/ a delay

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I have a `UIView` that is anchored to the `top`, `leading` and `trailing` anchor. It has an initial height of `138` and should shrink to no less than `88`.

I have a `UITableView` anchored top to the bottom of this view, it is also anchored to the `leading`, `trailing` and bottom of the super view.

It is not the header view for the table view, but a separate view.

On scrolling the table view I would like my `UIView` to shrink and reset back to it's initial size, depending on the direction of the scroll.

- Scroll up = shrink to no less than `88`
- Scroll down = increase to no more than `138`

I am currently able to achieve this through the use of

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    onUserScroll?(scrollView)
}
```

which through a binding triggers the below code

```
class FeedView: UIView {
    private(set) var brandedHeader: UIView!
    private(set) var brandedHeaderHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private(set) var tableView: UITableView!

    private lazy var maxHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 138
    private lazy var minHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 88
    private var previousScrollOffset: CGFloat = 0

    ...............

}
    extension FeedView {
        func setTableViewDelegate(_ delegate: TableViewDelegate) {
            tableView.delegate = delegate
            tableView.dataSource = delegate
        }

        func onUserScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

            let scrollDiff = scrollView.contentOffset.y - self.previousScrollOffset

            let absoluteTop: CGFloat = 0
            let absoluteBottom: CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height

            let isScrollingDown = scrollDiff > 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y > absoluteTop
            let isScrollingUp = scrollDiff < 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y < absoluteBottom

            guard canAnimateHeader(scrollView) else { return }

            // Calculate new header height
            var newHeight = self.brandedHeaderHeight.constant
            if isScrollingDown {
                newHeight = max(self.minHeaderHeight, self.brandedHeaderHeight.constant - abs(scrollDiff))
            } else if isScrollingUp {
                newHeight = min(self.maxHeaderHeight, self.brandedHeaderHeight.constant + abs(scrollDiff))
            }

            // Header needs to animate
            if newHeight != self.brandedHeaderHeight.constant {
                self.brandedHeaderHeight.constant = newHeight
                self.setScrollPosition(self.previousScrollOffset)
            }

            self.previousScrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        }

        private func canAnimateHeader(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Bool {
            // Calculate the size of the scrollView when header is collapsed
            let scrollViewMaxHeight = scrollView.frame.height + self.brandedHeaderHeight.constant - minHeaderHeight

            // Make sure that when header is collapsed, there is still room to scroll
            return scrollView.contentSize.height > scrollViewMaxHeight
        }

        private func setScrollPosition(_ position: CGFloat) {
            self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.tableView.contentOffset.x, y: position)
        }
    }
```

**What I would like to do however, is delay the resize event.**

Currently it starts on scroll up or down straight away, I would in fact like to have it start to resize after the user has scrolled X amount up and then only resize on scroll down when they pass that point again.

I updated my code as follows

```
private var previousScrollOffset: CGFloat = 100 // offset the initial scroll so the header does not shrink immediately on scroll
```

and then also

```
    func onUserScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        guard scrollView.contentOffset.y < 200 else { return }
        ..........
}
```

But this did not work as expected.

I am hoping to achieve the same effect as the large title navigation bar scroll effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `onUserScroll` function with

```
    let isScrollingDown = scrollDiff > 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y > absoluteTop && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 300
    let isScrollingUp = scrollDiff < 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y < absoluteBottom && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 300
```

You should get the desired effect I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple y-constants to start shrinking/revealing the top bar.

For example
If scrolling down and the bar is revealed and `contentOffset.y` is greater than 500 - shrink it.

If scrolling up and the bar is shrinked and `contentOffset.y` is less than 300 - reveal it.